# How can I order by count with pagination?

Tags: sql-server

I have to migrate some SQL from PostgreSQL to SQL Server (2005+). On PostgreSQL i had:

```
select count(id) as count, date
from table 
group by date 
order by count 
limit 10 offset 25
```

Now i need the same SQL but for SQL Server. I did it like below, but get error: `Invalid column name 'count'.` How to solve it ?

```
select * from (
   select row_number() over (order by count) as row, count(id) as count, date 
   from table 
   group by date
) a where a.row >= 25 and a.row < 35
```

Comment: I have no idea, but something I would look at is using the reserved word count as an alias.  Again, I don't use sql-server so I don't know if that is the problem.  but either way it is bad practice.

Comment: So people don't have to fork their answers like I did, can you please include *version* of SQL Server in your question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't reference an alias by name, at the same scope, except in an *ending* `ORDER BY` (it is an invalid reference inside of a windowing function at the same scope).

To get the exact same results, it may need to be extended to (nesting scope for clarity):

```
SELECT c, d FROM 
(
  SELECT c, d, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY c) AS row FROM 
  (
    SELECT d = [date], c = COUNT(id) FROM dbo.table GROUP BY [date]
  ) AS x
) AS y WHERE row >= 25 AND row < 35;
```

This can be shortened a little bit as per mohan's answer.

```
SELECT c, d FROM 
(
  SELECT COUNT(id), [date], ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY COUNT(id))
   FROM dbo.table GROUP BY [date]
) AS y(c, d, row)
WHERE row >= 25 AND row < 35;
```

In SQL Server 2012, it's much easier with [OFFSET / FETCH](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188385.aspx) - closer to the syntax you're used to, but actually using ANSI-compatible syntax rather than proprietary voodoo.

```
SELECT c = COUNT(id), d = [date]
FROM dbo.table GROUP BY [date]
ORDER BY COUNT(id)
OFFSET 25 ROWS FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY;
```

I [blogged about this functionality in 2010](https://sqlblog.org/2010/11/10/sql-server-v-next-denali-using-the-offset-clause-paging) (lots of good comments there too) and should probably invest some time doing some serious performance tests.

And I agree with @ajon - I hope your real tables, columns and queries don't abuse reserved words like this.

Comment: @marioosh Because SQL Server did this the right way, following the standard, instead of coming up with this LIMIT nonsense. You can use OFFSET / FETCH starting with SQL Server 2012. I didn't know if you could use that because you didn't bother specifying the version.

Comment: Also it's quite a bit simpler if you aren't paging based on an aggregate. You may consider an indexed view if queries are too hard.

Answer (score 3):

It works

```
DECLARE @startrow int=0,@endrow int=0

;with CTE AS (

select row_number() over ( order by count(id)) as row,count(id) AS count, date
from table
group by date 
)
SELECT * FROM CTE 
WHERE  row between @startrow and @endrow
```

Answer (score -3):

I think this will do it

```
select * from (
   select row_number() over (order by id) as row, count(id) as count, date 
   from table 
   group by date
) a where a.row >= 25 and a.row < 35
```

Also, I don't know what version of SQL Server you are using but SQL Server 2012 has a new [Paging](http://www.sqlservergeeks.com/blogs/AhmadOsama/personal/457/sql-server-2012-%E2%80%9Cdenali%E2%80%9D-paging-feature) feature